# card object changes after putting inside a own component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have created a responsive list of bootstrap cards which will be displaying information. The cards are currently created by *ngIf inside the page component. Now I want to move the card items inside it's own component. When doing this the formatting change.

I've tried encapsulating the cards inside their own ng-container (which still works without problems), but that did not help me at all.

My understanding of using components was that it should inject the html code like when using ng-container or am I missing one important point?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp4vA.png)

Working in one component:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let device of devices" class="col-4 mb-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>some content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Splitted into multiple components:

Page Component (page-list):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-device-list-item></app-device-list-item>
    <app-device-list-item></app-device-list-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Device Component (device-list-item):

```
div class="col-4 mb-4">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result: Devices should render the same way as they do when rendered inside one component

Actual result: They do not render the same way (see screenshot)

Comment: Can you show your CSS? Did you move CSS into inner component's CSS file?

Comment: You component will be rendered inside <app-device-list-item> element that will be treated as <span> by browser, you have to do styling that respect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with the CSS classes you have provided to the div which contains the `*ngFor` attribute, namely the `class="col-4 mb-4"` classes. You need to move those classes outside the device component.

Try changing your code to the following

**Page Component (page-list)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let device of devices" class="col-4 mb-4">
    <app-device-list-item></app-device-list-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Device Component (device-list-item)**

```
<div class="card h-100">
  <div class="card-body">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-child-component)

Comment: thanks that example on stackblitz worked out pretty well. I corrected your example, because it seems that you have missed a closing of the div, because you have two classes in one div, which is not working. I hope it is not a problem

Comment: @Timo glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your final markup will look as below, the content of `device-list-item` component is wrapped in `<app-device-list-item>` element that is treated by browser as `<span>` element by default:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-device-list-item>
      <div class="col-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            some content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </app-device-list-item>
    <app-device-list-item>
      <div class="col-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            some content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </app-device-list-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have to apply `col-4 mb-4` CSS classes on this wrapping element (host in Angular terminology) to apply desired styling:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-list-item',
  ...
  host: {
    class: 'col-4 mb-4'
  }
})
```